# I don't understand this concept about solution space and basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

"Solution space has a basis whose elements correspond to the columns of RRE form E which do not contain the leading entry of any row"

I don't understand this. Why is this true? Could you please give me an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would add that we're talking about a homogeneous (set equal to $0,\dots,0$) system of linear equations, correct?

Comment: Yes. Solution space = set of x such that Ax=0. A is a m by n matrix

Comment: I'm not sure what RRE form E means, but if you mean the columns of A once it's row-reduced, I would say this is false. If anything, a basis of the solution space could be considered the basis whose elements are orthogonal to the *rows* of A. Maybe "form E" adds something else though to make it true.

Comment: RRE form E is the reduced row echelon of A. Thanks for your input!

Comment: In that case, try with $\text{Id}_nx=0$ where $\text{Id}_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity. Clearly the solution space is the set with one element, $\{\vec 0\}$, whereas according to the statement it is the span of the columns of $\text{ Id}_n$, in other words all of $\mathbb R^n$! Something is wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reasons:

- Elementary row operations do not alter dependencies among columns of the matrix.
- In reduced row echelon form, columns without leading entries can be given as linear combinations of the columns with leading entries.
- The column space has dimension equal to the rank of the matrix (the number of leading entries).

To illustrate, consider the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ in reduced row echelon form.  The columns without leading entries (columns 3 and 4) can be formed as linear combinations of the columns with leading entries (columns 1 and 2).  For example, $$\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}^{C_3}=\color{blue}{-1}\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}^{C_1}+\color{red}{1}\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}^{C_2}.$$  Similarly, $C_4=2C_1$.

So any row equivalent matrix, such as $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 5 & 4 & 2 \\ 0 & 9 & 9 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ also satisfies $C_3=-C_1+C_2$ and $C_4=2C_1$.

We need $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ linearly independent column vectors to form a basis of $\mathrm{col}(A)$, and the columns of $A$ corresponding to columns with leading entries in the reduced row echelon form give precisely that (and they're obviously linearly independent in the reduced row echelon form).